# Docs changes which "need review" should be dimmed if I've reviewed them

Tags: feature-request, documentation, proposed-changes

The [proposed changes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift?tab=proposedchanges&subtab=needreview) tab's "need review" subtab is useful, but if my review action doesn't lead to immediate approval/rejection, then when I look at this list I can't tell which changes I've already reviewed and which I haven't.

Changes which I've reviewed already should be dimmed (or maybe ones I haven't reviewed could be highlighted...just need some sort of distinction).

Comment: [This is related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329598/removal-of-documentation-review-step/329619#comment373290_329598), I suspect this question may become less relevant once the review process is solidified.