# Removal of documentation review step

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

Documentation review process is slow and big pain point, which really does not add value. This process is not present for posting answers to SE question, which is right.

Even with this process,  low quality posts may be approved by low reputation users. High reputation users are staying away due to this review process delay.

Since we already have down voting mechanism, it will take care of low quality documentation. If you want to remove low quality examples, hide these examples with negative score of -5.

Current review process is un-necessary and should be removed as early as possible.

Related question:

[Contribution to documentation - Low engagement levels & high approval turn around time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329462/contribution-to-documentation-low-engagement-levels-high-approval-turn-aroun)

Comment: We're currently looking at the review process as a whole, and we need to have a bunch of conversations before we can give a proper answer here - it's _extremely_ high on our list right now so it won't be long.

Comment: I have added one more question in my post, which caused me to raise this question.

Comment: I wouldn't remove the review process. I'd have it require more than a single "accept" vote. Popular tags get way too many incorrect edits now.

Comment: "High reputation users are staying away due to this review process delay." that is not the reason we are staying away. It's kinda the opposite.

Answer (score 24):

> Since we already have down voting mechanism, it will take care of low quality documentation. If you want to remove low quality examples, hide these examples

No. If anything, the main site has proven that voting like that doesn't work.

Bad content stays, because not every post gets read by someone who can actually evaluate the quality of said post, and if it does get read, it doesn't always get downvoted because this leads to pointless discussions and pity-upvotes (especially if the poster of said answer is relatively new to the site).

Additions and edits to documentation *must* be reviewed by at least one Subject Matter Expert.

See also my related question [Reviewing changes after the fact](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328960/reviewing-changes-after-the-fact), where I argue the same.

Comment: *"...Subject Matter Expert"*: exactly this. I hope this gets built into the review process, otherwise anyone can approve changes.

Answer (score 9):

> Even with this process, low quality posts may be approved by low reputation users. High reputation users are staying away due to this review process delay.

That's not true. Many LQ-posts are getting filtered out *thanks to this review-process*, and what still gets through is mostly approved by either low-rep- or robo-reviewers. The process itself is good (apart from the delay).

High-rep-users are **not** staying away due to the delay that the review process has, they're staying away due to the sheer amount of crap posted on docs. Most users just don't want to dig through tons of LQ-content, edit everything that's wrong & spend hours on it, without any visible effect.

Another note: The [question you linked to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329462/contribution-to-documentation-low-engagement-levels-high-approval-turn-aroun) has an answer by [Nicol Bolas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas), who argues exactly the same.

> The #1 reason is that I don't feel like playing the part of Sisyphus, constantly fighting an uphill battle. That's what doing stuff in the C++ tag feels like. There's a constant deluge of poorly-conceived changes, topic proposals, and so forth to wade through. It's unending, and I don't want to deal with it.